# Swiper Touch Events - Enable click but disable drag

Tags: slider, touch, drag, swiper.js

I am using **Swiper 3.4.2** slider with thumbs as a pagination slider. And I need to disable drag on the pagination slider but to enable click events so the main slider can be changed by clicking on thumbs in the pagination slider.

```
    var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
        spaceBetween: 0,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        shortSwipes: false,
        slideToClickedSlide: true,
        preventClicksPropagation: false,
        preventClicks: false
    });
```

By setting `simulateTouch` to `false`, I am loosing the click touch event also.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Setting the `touchRatio: 0` will disable the drag touch event and leave the click touch event enabled

**Update from v4**

```
allowTouchMove: false,
```

Comment: For some reason `noSwiping` and `onlyExternal` didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

From version 4.0, you can use:

```
allowTouchMove
```

> If false, then the only way to switch the slide is use of external API
>   functions like slidePrev or slideNext

Answer (score 2):

You can alsow use `touchRatio` at breakpoints:

```js
breakpoints: {
    600: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetweenSlides: 30,
        touchRatio: 1
    },
    768: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        touchRatio: 0
    }
},
```