# SwiperJS - Is it possible to enable drag but disable click on slides?

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using swiper 8.4.4.
I'm looking to disable the "click" functionality, but keep the "drag" events enabled.

The parameter "simulateTouch" enables both the click and drag functionality. So turning it to false is not an option.

I see this post which plays with swiperjs parameters to achieve the opposite of what I'm looking to do:  remove the drag effect while keeping the click: [Swiper Touch Events - Enable click but disable drag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44115954/swiper-touch-events-enable-click-but-disable-drag)

Would you folks have a suggestion I might try?

I tried specifying the following parameters from swiperjs, but they did not help me achieve the goal of disabling click while allowing drag event.
`allowTouchMove: true, simulateTouch: false, slideToClickedSlide: false, touchReleaseOnEdges: false, a11y: false, watchSlidesProgress: true,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add pointer-envets CSS property.

```
.swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-slides-per-view-forked-r0ociq?file=/index.html:1428-1469